# Unknown type name 'thread_policy_flavor_t'; did you mean 'task_policy_flavor_t'?

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently erased my disk, installed macOS 10.12, then upgraded to 10.14.1 and finally installed Xcode 10.1.

Unfortunately, I met up with a compiler error:

> Unknown type name 'thread_policy_flavor_t'; did you mean
>   'task_policy_flavor_t'?

[see the error in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRIBi.jpg)

Does anyone have some idea please?

--- **updated** ---

I'm sorry for the late updating. I resolved it by following steps:

1. removed the Xcode 10.1 from Applications folder and empty the trash basket;
2. installed the Xcode 9.4.1;
3. **overrode installed** the Xcode 10.1 by choosing the "replace" option when dropping the Xcode app to Applications folder.

I think there must be something containing `thread_policy_flavor_t` in Xcode 9.x but are not included in the new version apps of Xcode.

Comment: Could it be in the lib stdc++.6 that have been removed (it was deprecated in XCode 9)?

Comment: @Larme: I tried to add back that lib as the steps of someone's experience on internet but it can not be fixed yet. It's confusing...